# replace div with results of another page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a div that has some data in it:

```
<div id='happyDiv'>
 <a href='#' id='a' class='clickMe'>A</a>
 <a href='#' id='b' class='clickMe'>B</a>
 <a href='#' id='c' class='clickMe'>C</a>
 </div>
```

When a user clicks on any of those links, I need to call another page and replace $('#happyDiv') with the results of the pages call. So I use ajax

```
 $('.clickMe').click(function()
 {
       var userData = $(this).attr('id');
       $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "someDir/somePage.php",
                    data:"id="+userData,
                   success: function(result)
                   {
                            $('#happyDiv').replaceWith(result);
                   }
              });
 });
```

I would expect #happyDiv to have the result data from the ajax call.  it does, but it also has the stuff from before the call.  The 3 ahref links.  How can i "replaceWith" so that the links are gone upon ajax response and im left with only the result?

The links are static and are there when the first page loads.

so what i end up with is

```
<div id='happyDiv'>
    ///REsults from AJAX call
    <a href='#' id='a' class='clickMe'>A</a>
    <a href='#' id='b' class='clickMe'>B</a>
    <a href='#' id='c' class='clickMe'>C</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `html()`... and it is better if you send your datas as object rather that query string.. clear and readable.

```
  $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "someDir/somePage.php",
                data:{id:userData},
               success: function(result)
               {
                      $('#happyDiv').html(result);
               }
          });
```

Comment: It's not possible. `html()` completely replaces the contents of the DIV.

Comment: yes .. i guess that is what OP needs rite?? `so that the links are gone upon ajax response and im left with only the result`.. not sure though

Comment: That's what he wants to happen, and he's saying that it's not happening even though he tried this. And that is simply not possible.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your DOM, is it have only one #happyDiv?
2. Check the result variable, maybe it contains this three links.

$(..).replaceWith replace HTML element, so it can't be exactly as you told.

Comment: Yea, i am going to have to scrub this page character by character.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the pure javascript code instead of jquery code to replace the content of your div, check the below code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "someDir/somePage.php",
    data:{id:userData},
    success: function(result)
    {
      document.getElementById("happyDiv").innerHTML=result;
    }
});
```

Also check that what you have got in response of your ajax request?